# Auto Invoice Check/Money Order Payment method

Tags: magento-1.7, invoice, payment-methods

Our 3rd party shipping software only captures orders that are processing/complete in magento. I would like to auto invoice orders using this payment method and this payment method only. So that as soon as the order is captured, magento auto invoices.

Clarification: Our shipping software (Ship Station) will not process/pull orders from Magento unless they are Processing status. With Check/Money Order Payment method in magento, orders are not automatically moved to that status from PENDING unless the order is manually invoiced in the Magento backend.

I am looking for guidance on how to set up an observer that automatically triggers an order using the Check/Money Order payment method and then a module that automatically invoices that order.

I hope that clarifies my need/question.

Comment: Hello kirkbrogan, welcome to Magento SE. We are happy to help you. Your question is not clear at all. Which extension that you are mentioning ? do you have any reference for this ? Do you have some code to show us ? Basically this question is too broad and an off topic here

Answer (score 0):

You should create an [simple extension](http://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/magento-hello-world-module-extension/) and have some observer to listen **sales** then do whatever you would like to.

In your `etc/config.xml`

```
<global>
  ......
  <events>
         <sales_order_place_after>
            <observers>
                <send_invoice>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>NameSpace_ModuleName_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>sendInvoice</method>
                    </send_invoice>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_place_after>
  </events>
  ......
</global>
```

Now `NameSpace_ModuleName_Model_Observer.php`

```
class NameSpace_ModuleName_Model_Observer
{
   public function sendInvoice($observer) {
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

    //check order payment
    if($this->_getPaymentMethod($order) == 'payment_method'){
       if($order->canInvoice())
       {
           $invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareInvoice();
           $invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::CAPTURE_ONLINE);
           $invoice->register();
           $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
           ->addObject($invoice)
           ->addObject($invoice->getOrder());
           $transactionSave->save();

           //send invoice
           $invoice->sendEmail();
       }
    }

    //get payment method code
    protected function _getPaymentMethod($order)
    {
       return $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
    }
}
```

**you will have to find out your payment method code and replace with `payment_method`**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Adarsh, is there any way you can help me a bit more to integrate this? I'm completely new to magento and am not sure where/how to do what you suggest.

Comment: I have explained all in my answer. What specifically you are looking for?

Comment: does it matter where i place/create the observer code?

Comment: Your File path should be `NameSpace_ModuleName_Model_Observer.php`. Observer class must be inside your Model folder. Did you check simple module development link?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could solve your problem by navigating to System > Configuration > Payment Methods, expanding the method that correlates to your Check/Money Order payment method and looking for a "New Order Status" field. If this exists, set it to "Processing" so that your orders skip the pending step entirely and ShipStation will pull them in normally.

I have attached a screenshot as an example. However, my payment method is called "Terms" in this instance.
[image: Payment Method Screenshot]

If you need a code-level solution to solve this problem, [Inchoo has a good post about automatically changing the status or an order](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-orders/automatically-invoice-ship-complete-order-in-magento/). Note that you will not want to automatically ship and complete the order as they do in the example.